# Android background shows circle

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm facing a problem in rendering the layout background image attached here on higher resolution devices.On few devices it shows well but fails on certain devices.

a) Samsung Galaxy grand renders the background with no circles.
 b) Samsung Galaxy s II  shows circles in plain background image.

I need to show an consistent image on all device versions.I hope 9 patch image will resolve this problem. Let me know your suggestions further to fix these problem.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: edit your question and add your code.

Comment: I have no idea if the image you have posted is how it should look, or is it broken?  What device is this from?

Comment: @Simon. It's my original image which placed I in drawable folder.

Comment: perhaps the image is kind of sampled when rendered, so it is not showing a smooth gradient.

Comment: did you add the 9 after image name on drawable folder??

Comment: @Candy.. the attached image is not rendered one.It's an actual image I put in drawable folder. While rendering the image on Samsung Galaxy it shows circles(I couldn't attached the screens).

Comment: You should take a screenshot from actual device to narrow down the issue.

Comment: add your code and xml layout for more details

Answer (score 1):

Your image is absolutely fine. I'm also pretty sure all of these devices display them correctly and in full color (in custom ROMs you can force Android to use 16-bit color mode which can cause color banding but I believe it's not your case).

I think color bandindg you see on certain devices is caused by low quality LCD matrices used in these phones which are not capable to display full gamut of your gradient.

You can find bad LCD screens even in phones believed to be "top devices". In my experience the worst color banding of gradients is on ASUS devices. Transformer TF101 is just so-so, but on Nexus7 even default wallpaper (the one with colorful blurred stuff) looks ugly. In contrary to these devices, Samsung's Nexus10 has a sharp and vivid screen with no banding.

Usually, the more is brightness, the less is contrast, leading to color banding. IIRC Samsung devices have various screen color profile presets, you can try to play with them.